# get component variables values into main application

Tags: apache-flex, components, flash-builder, flex4.5

i have a component which gets the data selected by the radio button

```
<mx:itemRenderer >
                            <fx:Component id="radio">
                            <mx:RadioButton selected="false" useHandCursor="true" change="item_changeHandler(event)">
                                    <fx:Script>
                                    <![CDATA[
                                            private var data_id:int;
                                            private var data_name:String;
                                            protected function item_changeHandler(event:Event):void
                                            {
                                                data_id=data.id;
                                                data_name=data.name;
                                            }
                                    ]]>
                                    </fx:Script>
                            </mx:RadioButton>
                            </fx:Component>
                        </mx:itemRenderer>
```

here there are 2 variables data_id and data_name and i want to use this component variables in the main application which get called when i click a button so what to do how do i call the variables values into this function i tried this

```
protected function delete_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dispatchEvent( new Event( Event.CHANGE ) );

                deleteTaxonomy(data.id, data.name);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then I would dispatch an event when the *id* and *name* changes and catch it in the main application. E.g. you could create a CustomEvent class *YouDataEvent.as* with the variables id and name. I often use this with my own objects and then send the object with the event. Lets call your object containing the id and name *YourObject*

```
import flash.events.Event;

public class YourObjectEvent extends Event
{
         public static const YOURDATA_UPDATED:String = "yourdataUpdated";
         public var yourObj:YourObject

         public function YourObjectEvent(type:String, yourObjInput:YourObject, bubbles:Boolean = true, cancelable:Boolean = false)
         {
            this.yourObj = yourObjInput;
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
         }

}
```

Then you can dispatch the event when the data changes e.g. in the *item_changeHandler* method like so:

```
dispatchEvent(new YourObjectEvent(YourObjectEvent.YOURDATA_UPDATED, yourObjVar));
```

And catch it at the main application with e.g.:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(YourObjectEvent.YOURDATA_UPDATED, yourObjUpdatedHandler);

private function yourObjUpdatedHandler(event:YourObjectEvent): void {
  //DO something
  var id:Number = event.yourObj.id;
  var name:String = event.yourObj.name
}
```

Hope this helps!